# Draw only objects inside canvas - Unity - World Space

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

Hi Stackoverflow community !

Is there any way to render only objects (Panels, Images...) that are "inside" the canvas.

I thought about using objects' position to see if they're inside the canvas rectangle, but the best would be to also render objects partially when a part of them is inside the canvas.

Like if the canvas was used as a "mask" of visibilty.

Thank you in advance every one ! :)

OuiMerci.

Comment: If you want to see UI elements in the canvas, Unity provides a Mask element for UI objects. For other objects, I don't see any fast way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stud pointed out, there's an easy to use "Mask" component made for the UI system that works like a charm. :)